# How to pass ProtectedSessionStorage to a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this custom delegating handler:

```
public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage;

    public CustomHandler(
        TokenProvider tokenProvider,
        ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage) : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenProvider));
        this.sessionStorage = sessionStorage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sessionStorage));
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return await base.SendAsync(request, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The `TokenProvider` class stores tokens:

```
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

Injecting these classes into a razor component work as expected.

I added an Api controller to the app:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage;
    private readonly ILogger<UploadController> logger;

    public UploadController(
        TokenProvider tokenProvider,
        ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage,
        ILogger<UploadController> logger)
    {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

However, when the controller is instantiated, both `TokenProvider` and `ProtectedSessionStorage` are null or empty.

Is it even possible to get instances of these classes using DI? And if not, is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score -1):

ProtectedSessionStorage, cannot not be injected in a C# class.  It should only be used in a Blazor component.  See the Microsoft docs which state...

"Protected Browser Storage relies on ASP.NET Core Data Protection and is only supported for Blazor Server apps."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server

Comment: Link and advice are correct yet I get downvoted twice.  Interesting.  Care to comment why if you did downvote?